# "Lifting a ban" — why does "lifting" mean "removing"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs

In all other cases "moving something up" means creating or increasing something, like in "rising concern" or "erecting obstacles". At the same time "lifting a ban" means effectively removing the ban. What is a historical explanation of appearance of such expression? I can only suggest that this came from the lifting a castle's gates which allows passage. Is this true?

Comment: The word "lift" is used similarly in a few other legal phrases, like "lifting an injunction". People occassionally talk of "lifting a burden" from someone, like "Hey, thanks for helping out, that really lifted a burden from me."

Comment: Not to be confused with *raising a hurdle*.

Comment: Different metaphor. _Lifting a ban_ (or _a prohibition_) means to move it upwards, thereby relieving pressure, so whatever's underneath can move. _Raising a hurdle_ (or _an objection_) means to move something into the path of forward movement. So, as Peter points out, it's kind of an opposite. Metaphors are great fun.

Comment: It goes with "under", as in "under a ban"; you "lift" it to remove this burden.

Comment: *Lifting* is also used in the sense of plagiarizing. "He lifted whole passages verbatim from Wikipedia and used them in his dissertation."

Answer (score 4):

It's a variation on the theme of lifting a weight off someone/something. You lift the heavy load that was restraining a man and let him move faster.

Answer (score 2):

To my opinion, "lifting" is used here to indicate some burden is now lifted from the concerned person or thing and that thing is now free to move. Ban is a kind of burden "put over" some action to freez it. So If you wish to remove it, then you will lift it from the action.

Answer (score 2):

> At the same time "lifting a ban" means effectively removing the ban.

"removing" is key here: when you lift something, you pull it off of the surface it had been on, i.e. remove it.